# Как заставить ruGPT-3 исправлять опечатки в тексте?

Tags: машинное-обучение

Я хочу попробовать заставить языковую модель ruGPT-3 исправлять опечатки в тексте. Может быть, кто-то уже пытался это сделать? Какие «затравки» использовали? Работало без дообучения?

Я пробовала некоторые затравки, но не получилось исправлять опечатки, модель просто повторяет текст с ошибками.

Comment: Вы хотя бы git приложили бы что ли

Comment: Или код сильно очевидный?

Comment: Код простой – затравка + текст, который нужно исправить -> токенизатор -> генерация с настройкой гиперпараметров.